# Attempted to load class "WebpackEncoreBundle" from namespace "Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I have a strange problem.
I use Symfony Flex and I work on existing project. I try to install webpack-encore-bundle with the following command:

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
```

Then I get this:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.2.*"
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/webpack-encore-bundle (v1.6.2): Loading from cache
Package symfony/webpack-encore-pack is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/webpack-encore-bundle instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class
Symfony operations: 1 recipe (8e557491367cda509fceebb187833635)
  - Configuring symfony/webpack-encore-bundle (>=1.0): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master
Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install --symlink --relative public [OK]

Some files may have been created or updated to configure your new packages.
Please review, edit and commit them: these files are yours.
```

Then I run:

```
yarn install
```

And I get this:

```
    yarn install v1.16.0
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > sass-loader@7.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 2.39s.
```

Everything seems fine. Now I refresh the project and I get this:

```
ClassNotFoundException

Attempted to load class "WebpackEncoreBundle" from namespace "Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

So here is what i have in bundles.php:

```
Symfony\WebpackEncoreBundle\WebpackEncoreBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

In composer.json I have:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

I run:

```
yarn encore dev
```

It compiles successfully but yet I have the same mistake.

I also tried this command:

```
composer remove symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
```

Then I try again

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
```

Then we I got the same error and this loop never ends.

Comment: When looking at the installation guide I don't see that you need to add the bundle to bundles.php. Try removing it. https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/installation.html

Comment: It is added automatically by Symfony Flex.

Answer (score 2):

I have this error and I just fixed it by installing the `webpack-encore-bundle`:

```
composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle
```

In my case, I had to install `doctrine-orm-admin-bundle` as well before `webpack-encore-bundle`:

```
composer require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Vagrant (e.g. via Laravel Homestead) or any other tool like this?
I found in this case, it was a folder that did not sync into the existing box.

**Issues one might encounter:**

- Webpack dependency has been installed after the project was already up and running in the box
- The vendor folder has been excluded from syncing process (it seems, it also caused to not update via re-provisioning)

---

*This might seem a bit off-topic here, but I've spent about 2 days on this issue myself, and I've not found any answers for this particular combination of issues.
That's why I am sharing it in depth with you.*

---

### How to fix

Let's assume the code is running in a box and synced to it, here's how to eventually check and fix for this specific scenario and dependency.

#### 1. Fix

1. Shut down the running box: `vagrant halt`
2. Check that Composer dependencies are up-to-date, or do so: `composer install` or `composer update`
3. Check that `Homestead.yaml` does not exclude the `vendor` folder to sync (?)
4. Re-run provisioning for the box: `vagrant up --provision`

#### 2. Test

1. SSH into the running box
2. Navigate to your source code folder
3. Check if path `vendor/symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` exists
4. Open project URL and check if it's working now

---

### Side notes

#### Vagrant + Homestead?

You might use any other tech stack for this - the fundamental issue behind not syncing should be similar everywhere.
For instance, in Docker this could be a caching issue, depending on your setup.

#### Homestead.yaml

Assuming you use Laravel Homestead with Vagrant with 'rsync' folder update, then you might want to include the 'vendor' folder
(be aware that this can drain sync performance). This setup is for Mac, but any other sync method should work similar.

I am not 100% sure if this is needed for re-provisioning, but in my case, it seemed to do the trick.

```
...

folders:
    - map: ...
      to: ...
      type: "rsync" # nfs
      options:
          rsync__auto: true
          rsync__args: ["--verbose", "--archive", "--delete", "-zz"]
          # rsync__exclude: [".git", "node_modules", "vendor"]
          rsync__exclude: [".git", "node_modules"] # Include vendor for any updates without rebuilding the box
```